# definition of weak formulation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

the definition of weak formulation on wiki is:
Let $V$ a Banach space. We want to find the solution $u \in V$ of the equation:
$$Au=f$$
where $A:V \rightarrow V'$ and $f \in V'$. This is equivalent to finding $u\in V$  such that for all $v\in V$ holds:

$$ [Au](v)=f(v)$$
Here, we call $v$ a test vector or test function.

We bring this into the generic form of a weak formulation, namely, find $ u\in V$  such that,

$$ a(u,v)=f(v)\quad \forall v\in V$$
by defining the bilinear form

$a(u,v):=[Au](v)$.

In poisson's equation we use the bilinear form ( $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$) :
$$ a(u,v)=\int _{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,dx$$
I don't understand how the equation:
$$a(u,v)= (Au,v)_{H^1_0(\Omega)} \longrightarrow \int_{\Omega}\nabla u \nabla v \; dx = -\int_{\Omega}(\nabla^2 u)  v \; dx$$
is correct when $V=H^1_0(\Omega)$ (i should use Green's identity but $\nabla^2u$ is not defined in $H^1$).
I know that:
$$\int _{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,dx=\int _{\Omega }fv\,dx.$$
is well defined but i don't understand how $$a(u,v)= (Au,v)_{H^1_0(\Omega)}$$
is well defined in $H^1$

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the Poisson equation, Lax-Milgram's lemma, tells you that the problem of finding $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that
$$
-\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla v  = \int_{\Omega} fv, \quad \forall v \in H_0^1(\Omega)
$$

has one and only one solution. This is the weak solution. A different question, that you can pose after you have guaranteed the existence of a weak solution, is wether that weak solution is actually regular, for instance if $\nabla^2 u \in H^1$, or even if $u \in C^2(\Omega)$. In a way, you derive the weak form from the classical equation but then they become separate equations (until you eventually prove that both problems have the same solution).

Comment: if i find $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ such that 
$$ \int _{\Omega }\nabla u\cdot \nabla v\,dx=\int _{\Omega }fv\,dx.$$ how do i know (using the definition) that $u$ is the weak solution of Poisson's equation?

Comment: You can establish that $\nabla^2 u = f$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$. See for instance https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.11f/lec14.pdf